# Parametrizing a side of a sector of a circle with natural parameterizations?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In the picture above, I'm confused as to how they parametrized

$$\int_{\gamma_3}e^{iz^2}dz$$

into the part highlighted in yellow. I get that in the integral over $\gamma_2$, they simply used $z = Re^{i\theta}$ and $dz = iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$, but can someone walk me through the parametrization of the integral over $\gamma_3$?

Thanks.

Comment: Should it be $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ in your last sentence?

Comment: Hmm? The parametrization of the integral over $\gamma^2$ is clear to me through $z = Re^{i\theta}$, but I'm not sure how they parametrized the integral over $\gamma^3$.

Comment: In the problem, they wrote it with subscripts rather than superscripts. That's the only point of confusion I was raising.

Comment: They did it the hard way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight line from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ can be parametrised as
$$z=\alpha+t(\beta-\alpha)$$
where $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$.  The contour $\gamma_3$ is the straight line from $Re^{i\pi/4}$ to $0$; substitute these values and you're done.